# Consulta SQL de acordo com a Coluna fazer uma nova

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, query

Possuo uma coluna que é numérica. Nessa coluna existem valores positivos e negativos. Preciso fazer uma consulta que quando for positivo, eu consulte a `Tabela A`, quando for negativo eu consulte a `Tabela B`. Não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso, tem como fazer isso?

Comment: tanto em procedure como no java você pode fazer um `if` pra validar.

Comment: fiz a consulta e utilizei LEFT JOIN e depois uso um if para verificar o valor da coluna e pegar o valor que me interessa, vlw

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução possível é :

Criar uma view que una as duas

tabelas

```
create or replace view v_view as
select cod,nome
from tabela1
union 
select cod,nome
from tabela2
```

Fazer o join na view

```
select *
from tabela3,v_view
where v_view.cod = tabela3.cod
```